# redirect traffic of an ip to another

Tags: networking

I have a little problem: a java program is trying to connect to an ip to the port 9001. The problem is I have no direct access to this IP. I can build an ssh tunnel in this way:

```
ssh -f user@<ip-intermediate-computer> -L 9001:<final-ip>:9001 -N
```

as you can see, ip-intermediate-computer is a computer that can reach the final ip.
How I can force my computer to ask localhost instead of final-ip? If the java program ask localhost instead of final-ip, the tunnel will forward the request to the intermediate-computer, and then forward to the real final-ip.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.251.3 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4
```